# How to use XML to Export data to Excel?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, data-export, excel

Can someone give me an example of using XML to export data out to Excel. I have been following the tutorial at:

http://www.pexlify.com/salesforce-exporting-data-into-formatted-excel-part-2/

But for some reason, my Excel first gives the error message:

> The file format and extension of 'Filename' don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do you want to open it anyways?

Once I click "Yes", the Excel freezes and then later on pops up the message the file is corrupted. What am I doing wrong? Following is my complete code:

```
<apex:page controller="ResultController" contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel#SimpleExcelToVF.xls" >

{!XML_HEADER}
    <Workbook
        xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
        xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
        xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
        xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
        xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
        <DocumentProperties
            xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
            <Author>Russell Keenan</Author>
            <LastAuthor>Russell Keenan</LastAuthor>
            <Created>2016-02-110T13:58:10Z</Created>
            <Version>14.00</Version>
        </DocumentProperties>
        <OfficeDocumentSettings
            xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
            <AllowPNG/>
        </OfficeDocumentSettings>
        <ExcelWorkbook
            xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
            <WindowHeight>12600</WindowHeight>
            <WindowWidth>27795</WindowWidth>
            <WindowTopX>480</WindowTopX>
            <WindowTopY>105</WindowTopY>
            <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
            <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
        </ExcelWorkbook>
        <Styles>
            <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
                <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
                <Borders/>
                <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
                <Interior/>
                <NumberFormat/>
                <Protection/>
            </Style>
            <Style ss:ID="s63">
                <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
                <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="42" ss:Color="#FF0000" ss:Bold="1"/>
            </Style>
            <Style ss:ID="s64">
                <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
            </Style>
            <Style ss:ID="s66">
                <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" ss:Vertical="Center" ss:WrapText="1"/>
                <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1"/>
            </Style>
            <Style ss:ID="s67">
                <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
                <NumberFormat ss:Format="Short Date"/>
            </Style>
            <Style ss:ID="s68">
                <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
                <NumberFormat ss:Format="General Date"/>
            </Style>
        </Styles>
        <Worksheet ss:Name="SimpleOpportunityExcel">
            <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="8" ss:ExpandedRowCount="5" x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
                <Column ss:Width="370.5"/>
                <Column ss:Width="138.75"/>
                <Column ss:Width="72"/>
                <Column ss:AutoFitWidth="0" ss:Width="42.75"/>
                <Column ss:Width="93"/>
                <Column ss:Width="56.25"/>
                <Column ss:Width="101.25"/>
                <Column ss:Width="83.25"/>
                <Row>
                    <Cell ss:MergeDown="1" ss:StyleID="s63">
                        <Data ss:Type="String">Open Opportunities</Data>
                    </Cell>
                    <Cell ss:MergeDown="1" ss:StyleID="s64"/>
                </Row>
                <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="30.75"/>
                <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
                    <Cell ss:StyleID="s66">
                        <Data ss:Type="String">Opportunity ID</Data>
                    </Cell>
                    <Cell ss:StyleID="s66">
                        <Data ss:Type="String">Type</Data>
                    </Cell>
                    <Cell ss:StyleID="s66">
                        <Data ss:Type="String">Lead Source</Data>
                    </Cell>
                    <Cell ss:StyleID="s66">
                        <Data ss:Type="String">Amount</Data>
                    </Cell>
                    <Cell ss:StyleID="s66">
                        <Data ss:Type="String">Expected Revenue</Data>
                    </Cell>
                    <Cell ss:StyleID="s66">
                        <Data ss:Type="String">Close Date</Data>
                    </Cell>
                    <Cell ss:StyleID="s66">
                        <Data ss:Type="String">Stage</Data>
                    </Cell>
                    <Cell ss:StyleID="s66">
                        <Data ss:Type="String">Created Date</Data>
                    </Cell>
                </Row>
                <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
                    <Cell ss:StyleID="s64">
                        <Data ss:Type="String">006580000034HRO</Data>
                    </Cell>
                    <Cell ss:StyleID="s64">
                        <Data ss:Type="String">New Customer</Data>
                    </Cell>
                    <Cell ss:StyleID="s64">
                        <Data ss:Type="String">Purchased List</Data>
                    </Cell>
                    <Cell ss:StyleID="s64">
                        <Data ss:Type="Number">15000</Data>
                    </Cell>
                    <Cell ss:StyleID="s64">
                        <Data ss:Type="Number">1500</Data>
                    </Cell>
                    <Cell ss:StyleID="s67">
                        <Data ss:Type="DateTime">2014-03-21T00:00:00.000</Data>
                    </Cell>
                    <Cell ss:StyleID="s64">
                        <Data ss:Type="String">Qualification</Data>
                    </Cell>
                    <Cell ss:StyleID="s68">
                        <Data ss:Type="DateTime">2016-04-10T10:40:00.000</Data>
                    </Cell>
                </Row>
                <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
                    <Cell ss:StyleID="s64">
                        <Data ss:Type="String">006580000034HRP</Data>
                    </Cell>
                    <Cell ss:StyleID="s64">
                        <Data ss:Type="String">Existing Customer - Upgrade</Data>
                    </Cell>
                    <Cell ss:StyleID="s64"/>
                    <Cell ss:StyleID="s64">
                        <Data ss:Type="Number">125000</Data>
                    </Cell>
                    <Cell ss:StyleID="s64">
                        <Data ss:Type="Number">112500</Data>
                    </Cell>
                    <Cell ss:StyleID="s67">
                        <Data ss:Type="DateTime">2014-03-21T00:00:00.000</Data>
                    </Cell>
                    <Cell ss:StyleID="s64">
                        <Data ss:Type="String">Negotiation/Review</Data>
                    </Cell>
                    <Cell ss:StyleID="s68">
                        <Data ss:Type="DateTime">2016-04-10T10:40:00.000</Data>
                    </Cell>
                </Row>
            </Table>
            <WorksheetOptions
                xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
                <Unsynced/>
                <Selected/>
                <DoNotDisplayGridlines/>
                <Panes>
                    <Pane>
                        <Number>3</Number>
                        <ActiveRow>4</ActiveRow>
                    </Pane>
                </Panes>
                <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
                <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
            </WorksheetOptions>
        </Worksheet>
    </Workbook>
    {!WORKBOOK_END} 


</apex:page>
```

And the Controller:

```
 public class ResultController {

    public final String XML_HEADER {get; private set;}
    public final String WORKBOOK_END {get; private set;}

    public ResultController()
    {
            XML_HEADER = '<?xml version="1.0"?><?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>';
            WORKBOOK_END = '</Workbook>';
     }
}
```

Comment: This question seems like it might be a better fit for [so]. Have you tried to [Import XML data](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-XML-data-6eca3906-d6c9-4f0d-b911-c736da817fa4)?